# Trouble solving system of nonlinear equations with piecewise

Tags: differential-equations, piecewise

Here is my code so far

```
R1 = 220;
R2 = 200;
R3 = 2200;
R4 = 22000;
R5 = 22000;
R6 = 3300;
R0 = 85;
Esat = 9;
E1 = (R3/(R2 + R3))*Esat;
C1 = 10*10^-9;
C2 = C1*10;
L = .018;
m1 = -1/R1;
m0 = (R2 - R1)/(R1*R2);
g[v1_] := m0*v1 + 1/2 (m1 - m0)*(Abs[v1 + E1] - Abs[v1 - E1]);

system = {i'[t] == -v2[t]/L , 
    v2'[t] == i[t]/C2 + 1/(R*C2)*(v1[t] - v2[t]), 
    v1'[t] == 1/C1*(((1/R)*(v2[t] - v1[t])) - g[v1[t]]), 
    i[0] == .03215, v1[0] == 1.5, v2[0] == .12};
 sol = NDSolve[system, {i, v2, v1}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

I am unable to get this to evaluate; I do not get any errors but it takes a ridiculous amount of time to evaluate. I believe it is due to the g[v1] function. I am not really sure how to pass a variable that is dependent on another variable through a function

Comment: The `Plot` and `ParametricNDSolve` commands will not work unless `E1`, `m0` and `m1`  have values. The `ParametricNDSolve` will also need values for `L`, `C1` and `C2`. What values do you intend to use?

Comment: R1 = 220;
R2 = 200;
R3 = 2200;
R4 = 22000;
R5 = 22000;
R6 = 3300;
Esat = 9;
E1 = (R3/(R2 + R3))*Esat;
C1 = 10*10^-9;
C2 = C1*10;
L = .018;
m1 = -1/R1;
m0 = (R2 - R1)/(R1*R2);

Comment: `R` is still undefined. BTW the equation set isn't nonlinear at all.

Comment: There is a piecewise function...